# Why am I getting a scope error when I try to call the delete function on an object I initiated using the New function?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm practicing with dynamic memory allocation, so I created an object here, a custom data type called vector3d, a math vector I defined in a different file. However, when I try to delete the object using delete, I get a compiler error that says that the test vector was not defined in that scope. However, I have a debug cout print function in the object destructor to make sure it is called and it is not being called.

```
int main()
{
    while(continueProgram == true)
    {
        vector3d *a;
        a = new vector3d("Test vector");
        std::cout << a->getName() << std::endl;

        vector3d b("Test vector 2");
        std::cout << b.getName() << std::endl;


        continueProgram = prompt(); // Boolean
    }
    delete(a); // <-- "Error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"

return 0;
}
```

Here are the constructor and destructor, as well as the vector3d print function.

```
vector3d::vector3d(std::string s)
:name(s)
{
    std::cout << "Vector constructor initialized" << std::endl;
}

vector3d::~vector3d()
{
    std::cout << "Vector destructor initialized" << std::endl;
}

void vector3d::printVector()
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << this->name << std::endl;
}
```

I don't understand why I can't call the delete function here, since I thought the whole point of using the New keyword was to preserve the object past its scope. Otherwise I would just initialize as

```
vector3d a("Test vector");
```

as I did with vector3d b, right? I don't understand why I would get a scope error here

Here is the console output of the program at runtime when I comment out the delete line and type 'n' to end the program:

```
Vector constructor initialized
Test vector
Vector constructor initialized
Test vector 2
Continue program? y/n
n
Vector destructor initalized
```

So there's the destructor that only appears for vector3d b, but not vector3d a

Comment: ***// <-- "Error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"*** The compiler is correct. `a` was declared inside the while loop.

Comment: How would I go about deleting the object? Is there a way to specify which object I'm referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that objects allocated with `new` exist as long as they aren't `delete`d by the program (or the OS after some time). BUT you still need the memory address to delete the object.

Without a pointer to the allocated object, you can't delete it. And that's what your compiler is complaining about: the pointer `a` doesn't exist outside of the while loop! And so, at the point where it sees `delete(a);`, it has not the slightest idea what `a` could be, as as far it is concerned it has not been defined yet.

So, the object itself still exists after the while loop, *but not the pointer pointing to the object!*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explanatory; though the object created using `new` *continue* to exist even after the `while` loop, but the local variable `a` pointing to it *ceases* to exist as it goes out of scope upon crossing innermost closing brace `}`:

```
while(continueProgram == true)
{
    vector3d *a;
    a = new vector3d("Test vector");
    //....
} // `a` goes out of scope
delete(a); // <-- "Error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"
```

Put `delete(a)` before the closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

You need the delete in the loop.

I.e. change the lines

```
}
delete(a); // <-- "Error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"
```

to

```
delete(a); // <-- "Error: 'a' was not declared in this scope"
}
```

So that `a` is in scope

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are declaring `vector3d *a` inside the `while`. Which means you can not use `a` outside the scope of `while`.

`while(true)
{//start of the while scope
int a = 0;
}//end of the while scope`

In your code, you are not deleting the `vector3d` that you are allocating in the memory every time inside the while using `new`. 
to delete `a`, move `delete(a)` inside the scope where `a` was defined.

Note: scopes can be created anywhere for example

```
int main()
{//start of the main scope
  int a = 0;
  {//start of a new scope
    int b = a; //a can be used here because this scope inside the main scope
  }//end of scope

  b = 2; //error b is out of scope

}//end of main scope
```

you can read more about scopes [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).
Hope this helps.